# how to plot data from a csv in matlab

Tags: matlab, csv, plot

I have a csv file with the following data structure:

```
p1_1,p2_1,p3_1
p1_2,p2_2,p3_2
p1_3,p2_3,p3_3
```

and I want to plot P2 againt P3 in matlab,
I wrote this code:

```
function plotData
dbstop if error
fileName='C:\\Temp\\out100-2.csv';
 m=csvread(fileName);
 plot(m(2),m(3));
```

but the plot is empty. I checked and m has data, so it is the way that I am using plot is not right.

How can I fix the problem so I can plot it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`m(2)` and `m(3)` are just two scalar values, hence you only plot a single point.

You need to supply vectors to `plot`, e.g.:

```
plot(m(:,1),m(:,2))
```

this plots the data from the first and second columns of your csv file.

Answer (score 0):

In your plot command

```
plot(m(2),m(3))
```

you are only plotting a single point. Perhaps you meant to plot to column vectors

```
plot(m(:,2), m(:,3))
```